# POST 403 Forbidden for ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

We're running into a strange issue with the development version of one of our websites. When triggering a postback on the page through a `DropDownList` `OnChange` event, the following error is displayed in the browser console:

```
POST <URL here> 403 (Forbidden)
Uncaught #<Error>
```

Viewing the generated IIS error page is not helpful. It indicates the following:

```
Module  ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0
Error Code  0x00000000
```

This is for a `ScriptResource.axd`. Now here's the strange part: this issue didn't start happening until our other developer started publishing the site. Previously, I was publishing it with no issues. There have been no `web.config` changes (in fact, it's identical to our production `web.config`, which works perfectly). I've scoured the web for clues regarding why we would be getting this issue, and it seems to be mostly related to either the `<handlers>` section in `<system.webServer>`, or the `<httpHandlers>` in `<system.web>`. The relevant sections are listed below:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
  <remove name="ScriptResource" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</handlers>
```

From what I've seen, this appears to match what other users say works well for them. One interesting thing of note is that the 403 Forbidden appears to be on `POST`. I did try adding `POST` as a verb in both of those locations for `ScriptResource.axd`, but this did not work either.

The website is hosted in IIS 7.5 under an Application Pool using Network Service. Network Service does have full control under the root folder for the website.

At this point, I'm at a complete loss as to what could be causing our bizarre issue.

Comment: i have the same issue i am getting error 403 when click button inside update panel for get scriptResource.axd?d=....... this happen only on the hosting server locally everthing working fine

Answer (score 9):

My Hosting use Plesk and I also met this issue after they upgrade the server.

After changing Web Application Firewall Mode to Off/Detection only, this issue is fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on the plesk hosting server, after tracing the request and check why it return 403 access is denied error i found that the hosting server has web application firewall (WAF) installed and this firewall block these request so you need to add rule to allow these request or turn it off.

Comment: Thanks, I had this issue. It took forever before I thought to look at the WAF

Answer (score 1):

For hosting companies using Plesk control panel, you can turn off the Web Application Firewall(WAF), but the purpose of WAF is to help protect your website from various attacks.  Instead, turn off only the specific Rule IDs that are causing the issue.  In this case, you want to allow .axd files on your website.

1. Identify this specific Rule ID that is being violated by opening the "ModSecurity Logfile" on the Plesk WAF page.
2. Search for the 403 Access Denied message in the logfile and then look for a substring that looks like `[id "942440"]`.  This is the rule ID that is being violated.
3. Switch off the "Security Rule" that applies to this issue, by typing the ID number in the "Switch off Security Rules" section on the Plesk WAF page.  In this example, you would type just the numbers "920440" inside the text box.

[image]